# Archer + Quaadrat Sans for a resume / CV

Tags: font-recommendation, sans-serif, resume, slab-serif

Is it advisable to use Archer (Hoefler) for headings with Quadraat Sans (FontFont), probably condensed, for the body of a resume / CV for someone working in teaching technology?

This website
http://www.typeconnection.com/matches.php
recommends Archer with Eurostile, as an 'embrace the other' strategy. Although I really like Archer, Eurostile is too severe for my tastes.

If you have any suggestions for a friendly slab (teachers need to be friendly) + square-ish sans (for a technological feel with a  human touch) then I would be very grateful.

As I'm not applying for the North American market, I don't think the Martha Stewart connotation applies. I would be happy to use Rockwell as the slab font. I like Geogrotesque (Emtype), Sanuk (FontFont), and Riga (Ludwig Type). However I'm new to the font pairing game and I don't have much idea. I did see advice about pairing fonts from the same stable. Impressive and distinctive though Forza / Vitesse Sans is (Hoefler-without-Frere-Jones), I find it a bit too severe. However I have no idea and not much taste, so I am happy to be wrong. Just because I don't like a font doesn't mean I wouldn't use it if advised, except Helvetica...

I have looked at lists of Eurostile alternatives on various websites but haven't yet found anything I prefer to Quadraat Sans. I considered putting a list of them here with my reasons for not choosing them but I didn't want this post to be off-puttingly long.

I ruled out fonts because I really dislike single-storey 'a', single-storey 'g', and 'r' without a spur sticking up over the shoulder, like in Maven Pro. Helvetica leaves me cold (sorry) and Meta isn't for me (sorry Erik, though I do rate Meta Serif highly).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Archer plus Quadraat could work.

[image]

(mockup of both in medium weight)

Though I'd strongly suggest playing with the weights. Because as you can see, the medium weights (with headers being slightly bigger) are quite similar. And this similarity but not quite matching is what clashes. Generally headers are a bit thicker (although sometimes hairlines are used for contrast) but in this case the header is slightly lighter but the bread text isn't heavy enough for it to really work.

I'd use Archer semibold + Quadraat extra light, or Archer bold + Quadraat light:
[image]

Perhaps using a light or hairline variation for very large, illustrative text, although I don't think that really applies to a resumé. After all, you're in education, not DTP/magazine design.
[image]

But honestly? Quadraat is a somewhat generic, yet weird feeling font. At least in this pairing. Archer, like Rockwell, is quite geometric and stylized. Quadraat has none of that, and it even feels a bit like it's slightly oblique by default. Look how the 'O' wobbles when mirrored:

[image]

## You could look for Eurostile alternatives:

Have you considered something like [neo sans](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/neo-sans/) for example?

[image]

Or [Exo](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo?q%5Bterm%5D=square&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y), Or [Lintel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lintel?q%5Bterm%5D=square&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y):

[image] [image]

All of which are squared, but not as extreme as Eurostile. Note the **s**, **e** and **a**, for example; a lot more open.

## Alternatively, you could go for Roboto:

[image]

It's a pairing that's literally designed to go together. The slabs also aren't quite as square as Rockwell but tapered a bit, and some of them curve in to the main lettershapes. The Sans isn't very square, but neither is  Quadraat, IMO.

Or look through [this list](http://fontpair.co/#two) of google fonts combinations, or similar sites.

## I personally use Sanchez + Century Gothic:

[image]
Though you might not like the single-story a, it's not bad for a teacher, since kids learn to write that instead of the double-story a.

Sanchez isn't the greatest font ever (most notably it only has 2 variations: regular/italic. no bold.) but it's a bit lighter/softer and more modern than Rockwell. It's also entirely free, which is nice.

Comment: Thank you PixelSnader for taking time to answer. I find it reassuring that I'm not alone in wanting to pair a slab with a sans. Thank you for your suggestion of the Robotos, I will try them on my resume. Ideally I would like to use fonts from different families as I hope to learn more about font-pairing that way.

I would still very much value your opinion about Archer + Quaadrat Sans.

You make a valid point about single-storey 'a' although I don't teach kids. I still much prefer a two-storey 'a' and 'g'.

Comment: @DocOctal Added a bunch more to my answer. As for font-pairing, I feel it's important to try and find similar fonts that have one or two big differences, instead of  a lot of small ones. This will show more clear contrast between the two.  E.G. sans vs serif, instead of slab vs regular serif. You can see how well this works within a single font: just make the headers bold and it already works.

Comment: Once again many thanks for helping. Your 'honestly' section is exactly the kind of help I'm looking for. I don't mind the asymmetry now that you've highlighted it. I had already considered Exo but I don't like the split in the 'y'. Neo Sans is new to me but again it has the split 'y'. Your answers have made me reconsider my choices and I am very grateful to you for that.